# Add a reference to a static folder from visual studio (2010 or 11)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, code-organization

I'd like to include some folders of static files shared between many projects and solutions.

These files could be images, script libraries or css that are shared between many projects.

I do not want to copy each time the folder inside the project structure but reference it just as we can link files between projects in the same solution so if any file changes in the referenced folder all the projects that link to it will have an updated version.

I know I can put it in a shared dll and embed resouces in it but I'd like to be able to choose witch folder to include.

Is this possible with Vs2010 or Vs11?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, its possible, and not even that hard. Put the files in a well-known location in your hard drive, then add them to each project as a link. See the second section in the following article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92.aspx

If you use source control, I would strongly encourage you to have at least one separate folder per solution file, and nest the folder under your solution root somewhere. TFS, in particular, gets antsy if your solution file includes locations that are outside the current workspace. (It will work but you may get strange warnings or errors, particularly if someone else tries to get the solution for the first time.)